# I don't believe that God is present in the Kabaa at Mecca, is it appropriate for me to pray the Salat?

Tags: salat, non-muslim, kaabah, qiblah

As mentioned in another question, I'm thinking of visiting a mosque on Wednesday around 7:50pm. I would like to participate in the Salat, because I believe that it is a beautiful and valid form of prayer directed to the true God (although many Christians would disagree with me on this point).

However I don't believe that there is any special significance in praying towards Mecca and I would feel more comfortable praying towards a tabernacle, a Eucharistic host, liturgical east, or nowhere in particular.

**Seeing as I don't believe that God has any special presence in the Kaaba at Mecca, would it be inappropriate for me to participate in the Salat (towards Mecca)?** Note, I'm not denying it, I just don't explicitly believe it, I'm unconvinced and leaning towards disbelief, but I don't actually reject the idea outright: it might be true!

I hope it's not an issue, because I've done Salat before and it was great. Such a wonderful way to worship God and I wish that Catholics would do it too. But if it's inappropriate because I don't share belief that God is present in Mecca, I will refrain in future

Edit: I'll note that I do believe God is present in the Kabaa, but only in the sense that God is present everywhere and in everything (omnipresence). So there's nothing particularly special about mecca: God IS there, but he's also everywhere else.

Comment: Just to clarify; Muslims don't belive God live in kaaba or is present in kaaba in that sense. Praying towards it is another subject though.

Comment: Ah, I guess in that case my question is why do you pray towards the kaaba? If it's for a reason which I don't disagree with then i guess i can go ahead and join in :)

Comment: I think that asking a separate questioning about that would be best.

Answer (score 2):

Kabaa existed before Prophet Muhammad was born, and it was a holy place then, as it is said to have been the first place built for worship. It is a place where Abraham, worshipped God. There general consensus is it was built by Abraham & his son, as mentioned in Quran 2:127

> And [mention] when Abraham was raising the foundations of the House and [with him] Ishmael, [saying], "Our Lord, accept [this] from us. Indeed You are the Hearing, the Knowing.
>
> Quran 2:127

And in the Quran 3:96-97, the Quran mentioned "Bakkah", which is another name for Makkah. Translator here chose "Makkah"

> Indeed, the first House [of worship] established for mankind was that at Makkah - blessed and a guidance for the worlds. In it are clear signs [such as] the standing place of Abraham. And whoever enters it shall be safe. And [due] to Allah from the people is a pilgrimage to the House - for whoever is able to find thereto a way. But whoever disbelieves - then indeed, Allah is free from need of the worlds.
>
> Quran 3:96-97

Additionally, Muslims didn't initially face Makkah when they pray. Al-Aqsa Mosque in Jeruselam was the first "Qiblah". This was later changed.  This can be read in Quran 2:142-144

> The foolish among the people will say, "What has turned them away from their qiblah, which they used to face?" Say, "To Allah belongs the east and the west. He guides whom He wills to a straight path."
>
> And thus we have made you a just community that you will be witnesses over the people and the Messenger will be a witness over you. And We did not make the qiblah which you used to face except that We might make evident who would follow the Messenger from who would turn back on his heels. And indeed, it is difficult except for those whom Allah has guided. And never would Allah have caused you to lose your faith. Indeed Allah is, to the people, Kind and Merciful.
>
> We have certainly seen the turning of your face, [O Muhammad], toward the heaven, and We will surely turn you to a qiblah with which you will be pleased. So turn your face toward al-Masjid al-Haram. And wherever you [believers] are, turn your faces toward it [in prayer]. Indeed, those who have been given the Scripture well know that it is the truth from their Lord. And Allah is not unaware of what they do.

Muslims do not believe that God is in the Kabaa. To support what you say, wherever you face, you face God, and this is in the Quran 2:119

> And to Allah belongs the east and the west. So wherever you [might] turn, there is the Face of Allah . Indeed, Allah is all-Encompassing and Knowing.

Answer (score 1):

First,  we pray towards Kaba because Allah ordered that way, if He ordered to turn towards another place, we would have done that way.

Second, Ka'ba is a special place, not like God is there as you meant but it is extremely just special place in the earth. But note that we dont pray to Ka'ba, we always pray to Allah. [For Ka'ba's specialities](https://islamqa.info/en/3748)

Finally, by turning towards the same direction, we show unity and being together which is a beauty of salah(prayer). And that something we desperately need to understand and do always

Answer (score 1):

I agree that @TheIronKnuckle has clarified his thoughts very well. And the posted answer by different people also added bit of value to clarify the concept.

Sometimes, very tiny things assist in resolving the confusion and understanding.

Allah or God (whatever the name we use in our cultural society) is not our servant or employee, etc.

- Allah/God is not bounded to do whatever we want him to do for us.
- He is not bounded to agree with our belief.
- He is not bounded to our behaviors.
- He is not bounded to seek our help or in other words Allah do not need us to do something or to have something happen .

He has created this life to see who is good in doing good deeds. In Holy Quran Allah has mentioned this thing in many places (in Surah Yunus ending part, Surah Mulk first iaya). Also he assist us in many ways when we seek help from Allah.

So we are required to follow the instructions and orders that Allah has given to us.